# jQuery - Several functions on one element

Tags: jquery

Im currently developing a wordpress site for a client, and they want to have a scroller which disapears from the click of a button and then shows content in a modal window blah blah blah ... It seems to all work, except when i put it all together when i click on a li element, it just displays the link in the address bar and doesnt go anywhere ... i have a feeling its got to do with disabling the normal function of a href but i wasnt sure how to get around it.

So for the scroller i have the following structure

```
<div class="scrollerone">
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""><img src="image.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="image.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="image.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="image.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="image.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="image.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="image.jpg" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The jQuery code i have is as follows ....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery(".scrollerone").jCarouselLite({
            btnNext: "#btnnext1",
            btnPrev: "#btnprev1"
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
        var list = jQuery('.scrollerone');
        var original_height = list.height();
        var new_height = '0';
        list.css({height:new_height});

        jQuery('#refl').click(function() {

            if(list.height() == original_height){
                jQuery('.viewcs').html('VIEW ALL CASE STUDIES');                                    
                list.animate({height:new_height});
            } else {
                list.animate({height:original_height});
                jQuery('.viewcs').html('CLOSE ALL CASE STUDIES');
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

If anyone could shed some light on this, that would be great ... I have a feeling that the return false bit disables the usual click behaviour, but it shouldnt affect the clicking on the li elements in the scroller should it?

Cheers,

Comment: Is `#refl` supposed to be the ID of the anchor tag?

Comment: Sorry, yes, the #refl is what makes the scroller animate like so <a href="" id="refl" class="button"><span class="viewcs">VIEW ALL CASE STUDIES</span></a>

Comment: Returning `false` will disable the click behaviour on `#ref1` with that code, but not elsewhere.  What else is getting disabled?  You say the hash is changing in the address bar, but no change in location on the page?  Are you sure you have anchors `<a name="thing">` setup for these hash parts?

Comment: Remember that anchors for hash-part navigation use the `name="thing"` attribute, not `id`.

Comment: Im generating the url in a wordpress loop ... the code is echo '<li><a href="#inline'.$ri.'" id="various'.$ri.'"><img src="'.$url.'" width="245" height="137"></a></li>';

Comment: and im using fancybox to display the modal on the li click which needs the id instead of name

Comment: Ok, it seems that the fancybox plugin gets sort of disabled when the the carousel plugin is running on the same element, is there a way to have them both working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

});
```

use event.preventDefault to stop the default event of the anchor..

Comment: Is there a way to turn it back on for a specific elemement? .. That might be one way around it

Comment: @bigjobbies, you can probably give a common class name for the elements you want

Comment: use id or common class like $("#id").click  or $ (".class").click

Comment: If the preventDefault is part of a plugin though, i wont be able to find it in the mess of javascript, can i undo preventing click on certain elements once it has been implemented by a plugin?

Comment: preventDefault() is a part of jquery , Also those logic you have to handle it yourself.

Comment: `<a onclick="myHandler(); return false;" ...>` works just as well, and is framework-agnostic to boot.